# How to take the derivative for the following formula?

Tags: derivatives, machine-learning

I have this loss function formula (for some given machine learning algorithm), with $L_2$ penalty added to it:

$$L(w_1,w_2) = -6(0.1 \cos(w_1) - w_1^2 - 0.5w_2^7 + \sin(w_2))e^{-w_1^2-w_2^2} + \lambda(w_1^2 + w_2^2).$$

The penalty is $\lambda(w_1^2 + w_2^2)$ and the rest of $L$ is the cost function.

How do I take the derivative for this? or more accurately, I took the derivative without this $\lambda(w_1^2 + w_2^2)$ argument. How do I treat the $\lambda$ according to the derivative of $w_1$ or $w_2$ ? Using the product rule maybe?

Perhaps something like this. Taking the derivative with respect to to $w_1$ and treating $\lambda$ as a constant number:
$$(\lambda(w_1^2 + w_2^2))' = 0 \cdot (w_1^2 + w_2^2) + \lambda \cdot 2w_1 = 2\lambda w_1.$$
This would just be added to the derivative of the cost function. Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: You must tell us if lambda depends on $w_{1}$ or $w_{2}$ or neither ("depends" here means: is a function of).

Comment: Lambda is the tuning parameter. As $\lambda$ gets higher, the bigger is the penalty, and the magnitude of coefficients is reduced. So it shrinks $w_1$ and $w_2$.  Hence.. $w_1$ and $w_2$ depend on $\lambda$. @Manifoldski

Comment: @Kev I don't agree: If $\lambda$ is increased, then solutions of $\min_{w} L(w)$ will be smaller in magnitude (that is, $w_1^2 + w_2^2$ will be smaller), but  $\lambda$ is a hyperparameter you choose a priori and is thus a constant with respect to $w_1$ and $w_2$. In this case the derivative you calculated is correct.

Comment: If w1, w2 are variables, you must use Partial Derivatives. Try to come up with an example to clear the dependency issue.

Comment: @NoChance why is this an issue? isn't the solution I proposed good?

Comment: The expression $(...)'$ is vague. It is meaningful if the enclosed function is of 1 variable. Here you have $w_1$ and $w_2$ as 2 variables. I see other issues but at least this is the major problem.